# How to configure nagios with mysql

Tags: mysql, nagios

HELLO!
I have installed nagios 3.2.2 and I am trying to configure it with mysql, but I cannot find the file "create_mysql", this file should have the necessary tables for. Ah! It is over debian lenny. Where is it supposed to be located?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Step by step explained:
http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/10-steps-mysql-monitoring-nagios-installation-configuration

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Sid normally, so it may not be the same, however, here's how to find out:

```
$ apt-file list nagios | grep mysql
nagios-plugins-standard: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mysql
nagios-plugins-standard: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_query
nagios-plugins-standard: /usr/share/nagios-plugins/templates-standard/mysql.cfg
... and some others less to the point.
```